# How to connect Sequelize to postgres in NestJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js, nestjs

I have been trying for more than a day now to get my NestJS app to connect to a postgres database on Heroku via Sequelize, and no matter what I do, it won't connect. I've tried every which way of doing it. Here's what I currently have in my `app.module.ts` file:

```js
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common"
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config"
import { SequelizeModule } from "@nestjs/sequelize"
import { AppController } from "./app.controller"
import { AppService } from "./app.service"
import { GameModule } from "./lib/game/game.module"
import { PlatformModule } from "./lib/platform/platform.module"
import { CharacterModule } from "./lib/character/character.module"
import { GameCharacterModule } from "./lib/game_character/game_character.module"
import { UploaderModule } from "./lib/uploader/uploader.module"
import { config } from "./database/config"

const developmentDbConfig: object = {
  dialect: "sqlite",
  storage: "./dev",
  logging: false,
  autoLoadModels: true,
}

const productionDbConfig: object = {
  url: "postgres://iqkjgqapygxime:603ae8965bd12621b2fbb9a4f2d25e34b3a7adc76c5f3bc4288858a4d52886e0@ec2-3-212-75-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d1rcd2nlivtm71",
  dialect: "postgres",
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      require: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  },
  autoLoadModels: true,
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    SequelizeModule.forRoot(productionDbConfig),
    GameModule,
    PlatformModule,
    CharacterModule,
    GameCharacterModule,
    UploaderModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I hard-coded the database url because at one point I realized that my env variables were undefined in this file for some reason. I thought that would have been the problem, but even after hard coding the url I still get the same error, which is this:

```
2021-06-14T21:25:37.625930+00:00 app[web.1]: SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2021-06-14T21:25:37.625930+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._connectionCallback (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:172:24)
2021-06-14T21:25:37.625935+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
2021-06-14T21:25:37.625936+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._handleErrorEvent (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:315:19)
2021-06-14T21:25:37.625936+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-06-14T21:25:37.625937+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:486:12)
2021-06-14T21:25:37.625937+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.reportStreamError (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:52:12)
2021-06-14T21:25:37.625938+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-06-14T21:25:37.625938+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:486:12)
2021-06-14T21:25:37.625938+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
```

I would be eternally grateful for some help getting this working. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Heads up, you should change refresh your database credentials **immediately**. Never post live credentials. You never know who will do what with them

Comment: Thanks. I'll delete the app on Heroku and redeploy when I figure it out.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? I am currently facing it too